# Angular Material custom form field doesn't show mat-error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I thought I have almost the [same example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55776138/angular-material-mat-error-not-showing-in-custom-components) but somehow the control tricks me :-/

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <app-ref-urlcheck [maxLen]="20" formControlName="url"></app-ref-urlcheck>
</form>
```

and the template looks like

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput #inUrl="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="value" type="url" [attr.maxlength]="maxLen" [errorStateMatcher]="errorStateMatcher"
    (input)="changeInput(inUrl.value)" [disabled]="isDisabled" [value]="strUrl" 
    placeholder="Homepage" />
  <mat-error>test error</mat-error> <!-- doesn't show up - neither the next -->
  <mat-error *ngIf="(inUrl.touched && inUrl.invalid)">This field is required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

and the main content

```js
import { Component, HostListener, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, ControlValueAccessor, FormControl, NgControl, NG_VALIDATORS, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ValidationErrors, Validator } from '@angular/forms';
import { ErrorStateMatcher } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatFormFieldControl } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ref-urlcheck',
  templateUrl: './ref-urlcheck.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ref-urlcheck.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: RefURLcheckComponent
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: RefURLcheckComponent
    }
  ]
})
export class RefURLcheckComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor, MatFormFieldControl<any>, Validator {
  @Input() maxLen = 254;
  strUrl: string;

  onChange = (changedUrl) => { };
  onTouched = () => { };
  isDisabled = false;
  touched = false;

  @HostListener('focusin', ['$event.target.value']) onFocusIn;

  constructor() { }
  onContainerClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
  setDescribedByIds(ids: string[]): void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
  userAriaDescribedBy?: string;
  autofilled?: boolean;
  controlType?: string;
  errorState: boolean;
  disabled: boolean;
  required: boolean;
  shouldLabelFloat: boolean;
  empty: boolean;
  focused: boolean;
  ngControl: NgControl;
  placeholder: string;
  id: string;
  stateChanges: Observable<void>;
  value: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.isDisabled = isDisabled;
  }
  registerOnTouched(onTouched: () => {}): void {
    this.onTouched = onTouched;
  }
  registerOnChange(onChange: (changedValue: string) => {}): void {
    this.onChange = onChange;

    this.onFocusIn = (inputVal) => {
      console.log('focus in', inputVal);
      this.markAsTouched();
    };


  }

  writeValue(value: string): void {
    this.strUrl = value;
  }

  markAsTouched() {
    if (!this.touched) {
      this.onTouched();
      this.touched = true;
    }
  }

  changeInput(inVal: string) {
    this.onChange(inVal);
    this.markAsTouched();
  }



  readonly errorStateMatcher: ErrorStateMatcher = {
    isErrorState: (ctrl: FormControl) => {
      console.log('errorStateMatch...')
      this.errorState = true;
      return (ctrl && ctrl.invalid);
    }
  };

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    if (control?.value.length <= 5) {
      this.errorState = true;
      return {
        tooShort: true
      };
    }
    this.errorState = false;
    return null;
  }
}
```

Same question as in the referred example: How to display `<mat-error>`? It doesn't even show up anyhow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56887035/custom-controls-with-reactive-forms/56893298#56893298

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reused the attached code and suspect that the `FormControl` didn't update with an error when the validation is failed.

When the validation fails, should set the error to `FormControl` as below:

```js
this.inUrl.control.setErrors({ tooShort: true });
```

```js
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

export class RefURLcheckComponent
  implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor, MatFormFieldControl<any>, Validator
{
  @ViewChild('inUrl', { static: true }) inUrl: NgControl;

  ...

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    if (control?.value?.length <= 5) {
      this.errorState = true;
      this.inUrl.control.setErrors({ tooShort: true });
      return {
        tooShort: true,
      };
    }

    this.errorState = false;
    this.inUrl.control.setErrors(null);
    return null;
  }
}
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kcl5my?file=src/app/ref-urlcheck/ref-urlcheck.component.ts)

Comment: Thanx - this works great. Especially the `inUrl` doesn't need to be manually injected (I have seen samples of this). But this means basically that my CustomControl is a wrapper around another Control (e.g. I could set an internal error state and an external one). Anyway thats interesting from a technical point of view. I'm happy with the provided sample :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanx to `@Yong Shun` I figured out how to do the management properly. It seems like that one needs to wrap an `input` field with the regular template driven approach (for the updates of the `input` field) and use this component as reactive one. So my custom control has inside a control which handles the states.

I removed from my original code all the unnecessary stuff and included some minor hints from the [guideline](https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control).

So here is my (streamlined) [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-newktr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fref-urlcheck%2Fref-urlcheck.component.ts) - for the sake when somebody needs it again.